# Comparing values with VARCHAR2 in oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying a very simple query which returns the results which are less than some particular value.  I am using the below query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ok_dc.gms3_vc_mme_vin_si_detail
WHERE
    vc_vin_locale = 'en_EU'
    AND vc_vin_document_id = 'SI120804'
    AND vc_vin_vis_start_range <= '670702';
```

However, as shown below the data returned is not accurate. The data type of VC_VIN_VIS_START_RANGE is VARCHAR2.  I read Oracle documentation, it was said that automatic conversion will be made while doing comparisons.

I need help with understanding what is wrong with the query or other possible solutions for handling this case.

Appreciate any help!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varchar (string) comparison is different then normal numeric comparison.

```
'1', '10', '11', '2', '20' => this is sorted string (varchar)
1, 2, 10, 11, 20 => this is sorted number
```

hence, you need to convert varchar2 to number when comparing

```
TO_NUMBER(VC_VIN_VIS_START_RANGE) < 670702
```

Please note that you may need functional index for `TO_NUMBER(VC_VIN_VIS_START_RANGE)`

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Is it the same thing with VARCHAR2??.

Comment: Yes string types are all behave in same way.